# how to map String on Radio

Tags: java, string, gwt, radio-button, gxt

I've faced the next issue:

I want to create CRUD-perations in gxt grid, but I've run into a such situation:
I made `sex` field as a `RadioGroup` on the form and wrote a converter for `create` operation(code below), so it works normally(entity and converter code below):

```
private Long id;
private String name;
private String sex;

formBinding.getBinding(radioGroup).setConverter(new Converter() {
        @Override
        public Object convertFieldValue(Object value) {
            return ((Radio) value).getData("value");
        }
});
```

Here is code for adding radiogroup to my form:

```
Radio radio = new Radio();
radio.setBoxLabel("M");
radio.setData("value", "M");
Radio radio2 = new Radio();
radio2.setBoxLabel("F");
radio.setData("value", "F");

radioGroup = new RadioGroup();
radioGroup.setSelectionRequired(true);
radioGroup.setFieldLabel("Sex");
radioGroup.add(radio);
radioGroup.add(radio2);
radioGroup.setName("sex");
simplePanel.add(radioGroup, formData);
```

I need to convert the value from String to radio and set it to the `radiogroup`.
but when I tried to write the opposite operation, i.e. editing, it throws me such an exception:

```
11:52:23.381 [ERROR] [hellogxt] Uncaught exception escaped
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.Radio
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.RadioGroup.setValue(RadioGroup.java:1)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.binding.FieldBinding.updateField(FieldBinding.java:207)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.binding.FieldBinding.bind(FieldBinding.java:82)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.binding.Bindings$1.execute(Bindings.java:92)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.CommandExecutor.doExecuteCommands(CommandExecutor.java:310)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.CommandExecutor$2.run(CommandExecutor.java:205)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer.fire(Timer.java:149)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I've tried to add some functionality to my converter, but it seems that binder doesn't invoke my code(formbinder doesn't step into the method at all at edit operation).

Answer (score 0):

In one block of code, you have:

```
radio.setData("value", "M");
```

Then, later, you have:

```
        return ((Radio) value).getData("value");
```

Since you put in a String (i.e. `"M"`) into the data with key `"value"`, when you read it back out again, you are getting that same String. As soon as you cast it to a `Radio`, you get this exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.Radio

I'm not sure it makes sense to cast to a `Radio` anyway, since you already *have* a `Radio` object - why not just return `value` if that is what you need? However, if that is the case, you don't need a `Converter` at all. Instead, you probably want that string, so shouldn't be casting to `Radio`.